# How to get docs in aggregated format in ElasticSearch aggregation query?

Tags: elasticsearch

My query

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_colours": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "colour"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Required Result:

```
{
  "took" : 2037,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "distinct_colours" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 34,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "BLACK",
          "docs" : [{
            "id": "block_doc_key",
            "avialability": true
          }]
        },
        {
          "key" : "GREEN",
          "doc" : [{
            "id": "green_doc_key",
            "avialability": false
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can I get the result docs corresponding to each bucket as I have mentioned above (in  "Required Result")? I am not able to find the correct query to get results like this. please help.

Answer (score 0):

The [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) can help you.

```
POST _bulk?refresh
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_color", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "color" : "RED", "avialability": true }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_color", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "color" : "RED", "avialability": true }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_color", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "color" : "BLUE", "avialability": false }
```

---

```
GET test_color/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "color": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "color.keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "avialability": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "avialability"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The [`multi_terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation.html) would also be applicable in this case

Comment: @Val Because of the fields are not in the same `nested`, I'm not sure if `multi_terms aggs` can help.

Comment: I don't see any `nested` fields in your example and also the OP didn't provide any sample documents hinting at nested docs.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, I was confused with the other questions :))). Yes, multi_terms aggs make sense.